Why is /proc/net/wireless empty?
I have a Linux device (v5.4.238) connected using Wifi on wlan0. If I look in /proc/net/dev I can see the expected interfaces:
# cat 
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
  sit0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
 wlan0: 37548733  374329    0  147    0     0          0     70999 66965219  295289    0    0    0     0       0          0
    lo: 24436513  260938    0    0    0     0          0         0 24436513  260938    0    0    0     0       0          0
 tunl0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0

But if I look in /proc/net/wireless it's empty:
# cat 
Inter-| sta-|   Quality        |   Discarded packets               | Missed | WE
 face | tus | link level noise |  nwid  crypt   frag  retry   misc | beacon | 22

Why isn't this being populated?
